# DMG cannot be opened because the identity of the developer is not identified even after sigining the DMG app stack overflow

Tags: macos, code-signing-certificate, dmg

I am trying to codesign the DMG application even after the app is signed from apple developer certificate. I am getting error of "DMG cannot be opened because the identity of the developer is not identified" while opening the app from the Application

I tried to sign the complete dmg generated from the appdmg and codesign both the ways

```
"code-sign": {
  "signing-identity": "Developer ID Application: ******* (4B9GHJ9X43)"
}
```

Verifying dmg signing from spctl

```
spctl -a -t open --context context:primary-signature -v **M.dmg
***.dmg: accepted
```

codesign -v ****.dmg && echo SIGNED!
SIGNED!
source=Developer ID

Another approach tried is signing the dmg again after the signing the .app

```
codesign -f -vvvv --strict --deep -s "Developer ID Application: ******* (4B9GHJ9X43)" ****.app
appdmg ./*****.json ./****.dmg
codesign -f -vvvv --strict --deep -s "Developer ID Application: ******* (4B9GHJ9X43)" ****.dmg
```

But i am still getting the same error

Any pointers on this is highly appreciated

Comment: To sign a pkg there's a different certificate that's required, which begins with "Developer ID Installer:". Perhaps this is the cert you need to use for DMGs too.

Comment: It is a complete application with bundle of icon and python files so i hope we cant use Installer certificate. But just for our try i have also used it i was not able to sign the dmg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to sign all the folders of the Frameworks that we are using inside the app and any dylibs that we generating ***.app/Contents/MacOS

codesign -f -vvvv --strict --deep -s "Developer ID Application:  Corporation (****)" ***.app/Contents/MacOS/libncursesw.5.dylib

codesign -f -vvvv --strict --deep -s "Developer ID Application:  Corporation (****)" ***.app

This will give you the prompt of your application is downloaded from the Internet do you want to open it and a Open button if are not downloading the DMG from the App Store